The dimension of the complementary set of prime divisors in projective space.
Let Div$(\mathbb{P}^n)$ the free abelian group with generators the closed irreducible subset of codimension $1$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ i.e. the hypersurfaces. We have a bijection:\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{K}[Z_0,\ldots,Z_n]_d)\xrightarrow{\text{div}} \text{Div}_+^d(\mathbb{P^n)}: [F]\mapsto \sum_{i\in I}m_iV(F_i),
\end{align}
where $F=\prod_{i\in I}F_i^{m_i}$ is the decomposition in irreducibles and $\text{Div}_+^d(\mathbb{P^n)}$ is the set of effective divisors of degree $d.$ Let $U_n^d$ be te image of div restricted to the class of prime polynomials $[F]$ then I want to prove that $\text{Div}_+^d(\mathbb{P^n)} \setminus U_n^d$ is close and has codimension: ${d+n-1\choose n-1}-n$.
Let's identify $\text{Div}_+^d(\mathbb{P^n)}$ with $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{K}[Z_0,\ldots,Z_n]_d)\cong \mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^d(\mathbb{K}^{n+1}))$. For $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $d=a+b$  define\begin{align*} \psi_a^b:\mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^a(\mathbb{K}^{n+1})) &\times \mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^b(\mathbb{K}^{n+1})) \longrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^d(\mathbb{K}^{n+1}))\\ 
&([A],[B])\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\longmapsto \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,[A\cdot B]
\end{align*}
This function can be factorize as: $\psi_a^b=\pi \circ\sigma$, where $\sigma: \mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^a(\mathbb{K}^{n+1}))\times\mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^b(\mathbb{K}^{n+1}))\to\mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^a(\mathbb{K}^{n+1})\otimes\text{Sym}^b(\mathbb{K}^{n+1}))$ is the Segre embedding and $\pi: \mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^a(\mathbb{K}^{n+1})\otimes\text{Sym}^b(\mathbb{K}^{n+1}))\to \mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^{a+b}(\mathbb{K}^{n+1}))$ the projection. Now thanks to the Segre embedding $\mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^a(\mathbb{K}^{n+1}))\times\mathbb{P}^n(\text{Sym}^b(\mathbb{K}^{n+1}))$ is projective and so $\text{Img}(\psi_a^b)$ is closed and then $\text{Div}_+^d(\mathbb{P^n)} \setminus U_n^d$ is closed since it is the finite union of this images for $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $d=a+b$. Moreover this is the irredducible decomposition of $\text{Div}_+^d(\mathbb{P^n)} \setminus U_n^d$, so its dimension is equal the dimension of $\text{Img}(\psi_a^b)$ for some $a,b$. But now I don't know how to compute this dimension.
Any help? Thanks.

@Daniel: Right, thanks for spotting the mistakes. I'll edit the question.
